# Resources studying affine geometry.

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

This semester I take a course of affine geometry at my university. Since I can't understand everything from the class and I'm the type who like to study at home, I would like you to give me some resources/materials/pdf/video tutorials/ and so on from where I could learn this subject. I would also like to mention that last semester I studied linear algebra so I know about vector spaces, euclidian spaces and so on. Thank you.

Comment: You're taking a whole course on affine geometry?  That's pretty awesome -- usually affine geometry is just a stepping stone to projective geometry.  What book are you using for your class?

Comment: I agree with @Bye_World : affine geometry is not a very rich subject, unless you mean "differential affine geometry", which is completely different.

Comment: I ain't using any book for my class. The instructor is responsable for our lessons. So far I know what affine spaces are, what linear combination affines are and some theorems and demonstrations about those.

Comment: @RaducuMihai Well, I don't know of any books specifically on affine geometry (that's not to say there aren't any).  I learned about affine spaces from Audin's [*Geometry*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540434986) and Kaplansky's [*Linear Algebra and Geometry*](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Geometry-Second-Mathematics/dp/0486432335).  I enjoyed both books but neither is specifically about affine geometry (Audin has a lot more on it than Kaplansky however).

Comment: Any help is welcome. I will try these and see if it is what I need or not. Thank you for your help @Bye_World